# merging two Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very simple question !
How can I merge two numpy array with increasing the dimension:

Suppose I have the following arrays :

```
a=[1,2]
b=[3,4,5]
```

I need this result :

```
c=[[1,2],[3,4,5]
```

However

```
np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
```

does not work !

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This array will not have many of nice `numpy.array` properties.

Comment: Do not get error. My result would be [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: I have two lists which I need to save them in a csv file. they do not have the same properties.

Comment: Normally a `csv` file has the same number of columns per line.  How do you propose to do that with these 2 lists?  Have you considered writing the lists individually to a file? Or with the `csv` module?  Don't force them into an array if you don't need to.

Comment: This is a bad idea both for CSV files and for arrays, both of which are designed for data with a more consistent shape than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the following to get the result you want.

```
c = [a,b]
```

Or

```
c = np.array([a,b])
```

**Result:**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Could you show the `repr` of `c` - to see type and dtype?

Answer (score 1):

Put them together in a list:

```
In [269]: c = [a,b]
In [270]: c
Out[270]: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Making an array from that doesn't work very well:

```
In [271]: np.array(c)
Out[271]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

But if your goal is just to write the lists to a file, csv style, we can do:

```
In [272]: for row in c:
     ...:     line=''
     ...:     for x in row:
     ...:         line += '%5s'%x
     ...:     print(line)
     ...:     
    1    2
    3    4    5
```

For a file just substitute the file write for the `print`.

`numpy` has a nice `savetxt` but it requires a nice 2d array.  That ragged 1d object dtype array does not work.

`itertools.zip_longest` can also be used to 'pad' the elements of `c`.  But simply writing to the file is simplest.

Using `zip_longest` to pad the rows, and then using `savetxt` to write the csv.  Note the 'blank' delimited 'cell':

```
In [321]: rows =list(zip(*zip_longest(*c,fillvalue='')))
In [322]: rows
Out[322]: [(1, 2, ''), (3, 4, 5)]
In [323]: np.savetxt('foo.txt',rows, fmt='%5s',delimiter=',')
In [324]: cat foo.txt
    1,    2,     
    3,    4,    5
```

with the proper padding, I can reload the csv (may need to fiddle with the fill value):

```
In [328]: np.genfromtxt('foo.txt',delimiter=',')
Out[328]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.]])
```