# How to merge two numpy arrays for each number in the first?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays e.g. a = [1, 2] and b = [3, 4]. What i want is to create an array that has all of b for each a: c = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]. How do i do this using numpy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1. merging two Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229811/merging-two-numpy-array) || [2. merging two Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561622/merge-two-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]


def mesh(values):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T.reshape(-1, len(values))


res = mesh([a, b])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]]
```